# Is there a way to insert data in oracle sql column where the rows generated is based on the minimun and maximum values given

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, sql-update

For example I have table called TABLE_A with columns COLUMN_A and COLUMN_B. COLUMN_A  has a 'Body Number' as data and COLUMN_B is empty but has a datatype of number. I would like to update or insert into TABLE_A to populate COLUMN_B with range values starting with 68900000 and ends up to 68999005 where COLUMN_A = 'Body Number' . So the rows i'm expecting to be inserted in  COLUMN_B is 899,005 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with a sequence:

Let's say this is your table:

```
create table Table_A (columnA varchar2(100), columnB number);
```

Create sequence like this:

```
create sequence testS 
  MINVALUE 68900000
  MAXVALUE 68999005
  START WITH 68900000
  INCREMENT BY 1;
```

And update your table like this:

```
update Table_A
set columnB = testS.nextval
where columnA = 'Body Number';
```

Here is a small [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3981ce06eedb9ec82154474d9981b4c5)

If you do get the error like "TESTS.NEXTVAL exceeds MAXVALUE and cannot be instantiated..." then you will first drop the sequence like this:

```
drop sequence testS;
```

And then create a new sequence with new values of MINVAL or MAXVAL or both. For example:

```
create sequence testS 
  MINVALUE 68800000
  MAXVALUE 68999005
  START WITH 68800000
  INCREMENT BY 1;
```

I have changed the MINVAL from 68900000 to 68800000 and in that way I have allowed sequence to generate 100000 more new numbers starting from 68800000 and not from 68900000. In this case I also change START WITH value to 68800000.

Comment: It updates rows that already exist in the table. Where does requirement "starting with 68900000 and ends up to 68999005" come into the game in your *small demo"?

Comment: I am assuming the OP has a tableA with a lots of rows and 99005 rows have a 'Body Number' value inside of the columnA. With this update he will update all empty(or not) values in columnB where the value in columnA is 'Body Number' and it will go from 68900000 to 68999005 as I have entered in the sequence creation. If he has more rows to update than he predicted then he will get an error: "TESTS.NEXTVAL exceeds MAXVALUE and cannot be instantiated" telling him there are more rows for update than he expected...

Comment: @Littlefoot I believe OP, with this: "COLUMN_A has a 'Body Number' as data and COLUMN_B is empty but has a datatype of number." is telling us that the data is already in the table...I can be wrong of course...

Comment: Well, yes ... that's possible, but - in my opinion - not probable. We'll see, if the OP ever responds to what we wrote.

Comment: @Littlefoot he does have more than one alternative now... and that is good right :) ? Well, in his previous questions the OP was not very active :)

Comment: Ah; after all, if your option is accepted, it seems that there **are** that many empty rows. Oh well.

Comment: @VBoka - You're right, I did get that error just now. How can this be solved?

Comment: If you have more rows you need to update then you just need to change MINVALUE or MAXVALUE of the sequence. I will update my answer...

Answer (score 2):

That's `INSERT`, I presume, unless you already have that number of rows in the table.

By the way, you expect too many rows; difference of those two numbers isn't 899.005.

```
SQL> create table table_a (column_a varchar2(20), column_b number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into table_a (column_a, column_b)
  2  select 'Body Number', 68900000 + level - 1 column_b
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 68999005 - 68900000 + 1;

99006 rows created.

SQL> select min(column_b), max(column_b) from table_a;

MIN(COLUMN_B) MAX(COLUMN_B)
------------- -------------
     68900000      68999005

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `COLUMN_A` already has data as `'Body Number'` in your `TABLE_A` then you can update that rows with `analytical function` to set `COLUMN_B` as following:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET
    COLUMN_B = CASE
                WHEN rownum  <= 899005 
                THEN rownum  + 68900000 - 1
               END
WHERE
    COLUMN_A = 'Body Number';
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I'm afraid it'll return "ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here". Besides, such an approach would update only limited number of rows, unless there are 99006 rows that contain 'Body Number' in column_a (which isn't probable, I think).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me this will do the job

```
update table_a
   set column_b = (68900000 - 1) + rownum
 where column_a = 'Body number'
   and (68900000 - 1) + rownum < 68999005;
```

And as Littlefoot mentioned, the difference between 68900000 and 68999005 is just 99005, not 899005